# What is the minimum pressure for existence of a liquid solution?

Tags: physical-chemistry, aqueous-solution

> The minimum pressure for the existence of liquid solution is?
>
> 1. $0.6\;\mathrm{atm}$
> 2. $0.8\;\mathrm{atm}$
> 3. $0.77\;\mathrm{atm}$
> 4. $0.9\;\mathrm{atm}$

Although this seems to be an informative question, I want to know the process by which we get this answer.

I know that the critical pressure for a liquid solution is $p={ a\over {27b^2}}$ but what is the value of a and b in that case?

I expect an easy to understand answer for high-school level.

Comment: My answer makes an attempt at this problem, but something quickly breaks down in the results of the maths. Can you provide some information on the origin of that $p=\dfrac{a}{27b^2}$ equation?

Comment: Very concentrated aqueous brine solutions seem to flow on the surface of Mars in the summer, where the atmospheric pressure is as low as 0.01 atm. They don't last indefinitely and pool in lakes, however, because it's only just above the triple point pressure of pure water (0.006 atm), and Mars is usually quite cold, so they tend to freeze or evaporate easily. But as long as a liquid is above its triple point pressure, solutions should be possible in a range of temperatures. In fact, concentrated solutions can be stable at pressures slightly below the triple point pressure of the pure solvent

Comment: @NicolauSakerNeto Yes,you're right..But since i have to zero down on only one option..(all options are above the triple point pressure of water)I can't really understand what to do.The correct answer is $0.77 atm$ and so how we arrived that is the problem.

Comment: Either you omitted something, or you can safely prove to your exam committee that the question does not give enough information to answer it properly.

Answer (score 1):

The only things I can figure for $a$ and $b$ in $p=\dfrac{a}{27b^2}$ are the coefficients from the [van der Waals equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waals_equation) for nonideal gases:

$$\left(p+\dfrac{n^2a}{V^2}\right)\left(V-nb\right)=nRT$$

These constants have appropriate units to give you pressure: $a\ \left( \dfrac{\text{L}^2 \ \text{atm}}{\text{mol}^2}\right)$ and $b \ \left(\dfrac{\text{L}}{\text{mol}} \right)$.

$$\dfrac{a}{27b^2}\implies\dfrac{\dfrac{\text{L}^2 \ \text{atm}}{\text{mol}^2}}{27\left(\dfrac{\text{L}}{\text{mol}}\right)^2}=\dfrac{\text{atm}}{27}\implies p$$

However, these constants are empirically derived, and thus [different for every substance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waals_constants_%28data_page%29), and so the critical pressure would be different for every substance.

For example, for argon $a=1.355 \ \dfrac{\text{L}^2 \ \text{atm}}{\text{mol}^2}$ and $b=0.0320\ \dfrac{\text{L}}{\text{mol}}$, so $p$ for argon is

$$p=\dfrac{1.355\ \dfrac{\text{L}^2 \ \text{atm}}{\text{mol}^2}}{27\left( 0.0320\ \dfrac{\text{L}}{\text{mol}} \right)^2}=49.01\ \text{atm}$$

Were you told which substance you should be using? For all substances, $b$ appears to be less than $1$, so we need to find the minimum $a$ and maximum $b$ combination to get the minimum $p$. However, by my calculation, all values of $p$ will be greater than $1$. The value for water is $220.5\text{ atm}$ (which does not make sense given that a vast number of liquid solutions are stable at normal atmosphere pressure).

Comment: No,I wasn't told which substance, but I have been asked about it in general.I have posted the question as it was, and no other data is given to me.The answer should come to $0.77 atm$but how should I arrive at it is a problem.See,using the critical pressure relation is my assumption over it,and I'm not certain about it.The reason I posted.

Comment: The use of the equation is imo correct and it refers to the pressure of the [critical point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_point_(thermodynamics)) - for water this is 218 atm, so you are very close. However, I do not see how you can use this equation for the given problem. (But I do not have any clue whatsoever.)

Comment: Also it's liquid 'solution' as stated in the question, so its not pure either. Its either a really good question or as @permekra stated there might be a lack in proper information.

Answer (score -3):

The minimum pressure for the existence of a liquid solution is just below 1 atm. Because at 1 atm pressure(vapour pressure) every liquid gets boiled off corresponding to the temperature at which it attains the atmospheric pressure as it's vapour pressure.